# Lost Intellisense in MVC. Help!

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2, intellisense

This is somewhat bizzare.  I've migrated my VS2010 solution to a new PC.  Everything is fine, solution runs, however MVC extension methods are not showing up in Intellisense!  I am at a loss.  I've seen a few posts on the topic but noone had real solutions.

Any tips are appreciated it.  Project runs on dev web server.  MVC is v2
VS2010 has been updated to SP1

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

- Close VS2010
- Delete files in the ReflectedSchemas folder
- Restart VS2010, open your project

Folder location:

**C:\Documents and Settings\username\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ReflectedSchemas**

New *ReflectedSchemas* files will be created when the project is re-opened.